# Hacer click en una imagen de una pestaña

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

En una página web tengo varias pestañas, y una de las pestañas se llama "figuras". Al pulsar en la pestaña figuras se oculta el `div` que estaba visible y queda visible el `div` de figuras.

Quiero que al hacer click en la imagen me salte un `alert()`, pero no funciona. No sé si es porque hay muchos `div`s de por medio y eso hace que no se pueda hacer click en la imagen, o si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Éste es mi código:

```
 $('img').on("click",function () {
    alert('wadus');
 });
```

También he probado con:

```
$('img').click(function () {
  alert('wdadus');
});
```

Éste es el HTML que genera el cms drupal8:

```
<div class="articulo-tab-figuras view view-articulo view-id-articulo view-display-id-articulo_tab_figuras js-view-dom-id-023890f0e12f609ee90464419f59d4dc1ad096990445609ebc4002873e4b0e20">
  <div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row">
      <div data-history-node-id="203" class="node node--type-articulo node--view-mode-articulo-tab-figuras-y-tablas ds-1col clearfix">
        <div class="js-view-dom-id-3b12a637eee985a77d3cec583680aac1aa336b67bfa832ab531112e806f39e1c">
          <div class="views-row">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                <img src="http://fondosciencia.local/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/borrador/2017-05/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202017-05-11%2019-21-45.png?itok=GYQLKbTO" alt="Esta es una imagen rara" title="Este es el título de la imagen rara" style="width: 220px;"
                id="modal-" class="image-miniature" data-target="modal-">
              </div>
              <div class="box-figura-delta .col-12 .col-md-8">
                <span class="label-figura-delta">Figura </span>
                <span class="field-figura-delta">0</span>
                <div class="field-content">
                  <p>Esta es la descripción larga de la imagen para saber de que va la imagen</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-0" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Esta es una imagen rara" title="Este es el título de la imagen rara">
                    <div>
                      <div class="box-figura-delta">
                        <span class="label-figura-delta">Figura </span>
                        <span class="field-figura-delta">0</span>
                      </div>
                      <p>Esta es la descripción larga de la imagen para saber de que va la imagen</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="field-creative-commons">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-referencia">
                      Rev Esp Artrosc Cir Articul 2016;23:112-7
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-doi">
                      DOI: 10.1016/j.reaca.2016.06.001
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-autores-nombre">
                      <p>Alejandro Espejo Reina, Enrique Sevillano Pérez, María Josefa Espejo Reina, Maximiano Lombardo Torre, Alejandro Espejo Baena</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="views-row">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
                <img src="http://fondosciencia.local/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/borrador/2017-05/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202017-03-31%2021-12-30.png?itok=qmqi2OU8" alt="Esto es otro alt" title="Esto es un title alternativo de la imagen." style="width: 220px;"
                id="modal-" class="image-miniature" data-target="modal-">
              </div>
              <div class="box-figura-delta .col-12 .col-md-8">
                <span class="label-figura-delta">Figura </span>
                <span class="field-figura-delta">1</span>
                <div class="field-content">
                  <p>Esto es otra descripción larga para saber de que va la imagen</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="modal-1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Esto es otro alt" title="Esto es un title alternativo de la imagen.">
                    <div>
                      <div class="box-figura-delta">
                        <span class="label-figura-delta">Figura </span>
                        <span class="field-figura-delta">1</span>
                      </div>
                      <p>Esto es otra descripción larga para saber de que va la imagen</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="field-creative-commons">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-referencia">
                      Rev Esp Artrosc Cir Articul 2016;23:112-7
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-doi">
                      DOI: 10.1016/j.reaca.2016.06.001
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-autores-nombre">
                      <p>Alejandro Espejo Reina, Enrique Sevillano Pérez, María Josefa Espejo Reina, Maximiano Lombardo Torre, Alejandro Espejo Baena</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field field--name-field-articulo-tabla field--type-text-long field--label-above">
          <div class="field--label">Tablas</div>
          <div class="field__items">
            <div class="field--item">
              <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="field--item">
              <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema (incluyendo JS y CSS y no sólo el HTML). Con el código que compartes, no se puede reproducir el problema (puse el HTML y JS en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLcLfzgu/) y funciona perfectamente) y podría ocurrir por muchos motivos: jQuery no se está incluyendo bien, estás ejecutando el código antes de que se cargue jQuery, estás ejecutando el código antes de que se carguen las imágenes...

Comment: te falta el '# ' o '.' en el  $('img').on("click",function () {

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estaba invocando bien Jquery con Drupal, y por eso no funcionaba correctamente.

Esta es la forma correcta de cargar funciones de jquery en Drupal 8.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
// js genérico del theme
    Drupal.behaviors.gpcbreezeModalShow = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            $('.image-miniature').click(function () {
                var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
                var modal_id = $(this).data('target');
                $('#' + modal_id + 'img .img-responsive').attr('src', img_src).modal('show');
            });

        }
    };




})(jQuery, Drupal);
```